# как сделать "новую" основную ветку на GitHub вместо изначальной main?

Tags: git, github

В ветке main были исходники проекта , я смержил pr с изменениями в main и теперь в моем main'e есть ненужный код. Как мне сделать новую ветку и сделать ее основной перетащив туда исходники проекта?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете сделать новый коммит, откатывающий ваши изменения или создать новую ветку и сделать ее дефолтной как написано в [документации Github](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/changing-the-default-branch).

Comment: Ваш ответ "слишком короткий".  Хорошо было бы, если в ответе была бы последовательность команд/действий, которая бы привела автора вопроса к желаемому результату

Answer (score -1):

Зайдите в ваш проект на гитхабе, нажмите на текущую ветку, а после назовите новую и нажмите make from [ваша ветка]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]